# Firebase app check backend implementation for Java/Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, firebase, firebase-app-check

I want to implement the firebase app check backend implementation for Java/Springboot (Maven). The official documentation only provides for nodejs and python implementations but it provides steps for how to implement it in other custom backends ([text](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-resource-backend#other)). I tried to do it with auth0.JWT but did not success.

`DecodedJWT x = JWT.decode(appCheckToken);`

This did not give me decoded token and I want it to access some properties to validate algorithm etc as mentioned in the documentation.